# Option to readlink on Linux and MacOS that will return filepath if it's not a symlink

Tags: linux, bash, shell, osx, readlink

I have this:

```
file_path="/actual/file/path"
read_link="$(readlink "$file_path")"  # just in case it's a symlink
```

readlink will echo an empty string if it's not a symlink? Is there an option to readlink that will just echo the original path if it's not a symlink?

Comment: Make a wrapper function

Comment: Try flags `f and m`.

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv are there such flags on MacOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a GNU/Linux system, the `-f` flag to `readlink` (`--canonicalize`), « *canonicalize  by  following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively* » will do this for you:

```
touch /tmp/real
ln -s /tmp/real /tmp/link

readlink -f /tmp/real    # → "/tmp/real"
readlink -f /tmp/link    # → "/tmp/real"
```

For a Mac OSX system, there is no option to do this, « *If the given argument is not a symbolic link, `readlink` will print nothing and exit with an error* ».

For both systems you can find the documentation and all available options for `readlink` with `man readlink`.

The closest you can get is to a general-purpose solution on OSX is something like this function

```
readlinkorreal() { readlink "$1" || echo "$1"; }

readlinkorreal /tmp/real    # → "/tmp/real"
readlinkorreal /tmp/link    # → "/tmp/real"
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, this works, if someone did downvote perhaps it's because they think the -m or -e option could work? I think your wrapper func makes sense

Comment: There is no `-m` or `e` option on the Mac. That's why I suggested the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Given the following file structure:

```
test/
├── link -> no-link
└── no-link
```

The `-m` option seems to do the trick.

```
florin@debian:/tmp/test$ readlink -m link 
/tmp/test/no-link
florin@debian:/tmp/test$ readlink -m no-link 
/tmp/test/no-link
```

Comment: And so does `-e` and `-f` in this case.

Comment: There is no `-m` option on the Mac version of `readlink`

Answer (score 1):

`readlink -f` does this (as mentioned in @roaima’s answer).

macOS 12.3 has [added support](https://scriptingosx.com/2022/03/some-cli-updates-in-macos-monterey/) for this option, so you can now use it on Linux and macOS.